# New-AzDataLakeGen2Item returns 409: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to loop through a local directory and write some .json files to a storage account (data lake gen 2) using powershell. I'm able to create a new directory, but after trying to upload a file to the new directory I'm receiving an error:

```
The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity. HTTP Status Code: 409 - HTTP Error Message: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity.
                     ErrorCode: OperationNotAllowedInCurrentState
                     ErrorMessage: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity.
                     RequestId:4ef174e6-101e-0070-49cf-abb721000000
                     Time:2022-08-09T09:07:58.7763954Z
```

This is my code:

```
$DataLakeDetails = @{
    Context    = New-AzStorageContext `
        -UseConnectedAccount `
        -StorageAccountName $(Get-AzName @NameDetails -ResourceType 'dls' -Separator '')
    FileSystem = 'dls'
}


Add-NewFileAzDataLakeGen2Item @DataLakeDetails -Source "path/to/.json" -Path "some/dir/dir/_delta_log"


function Add-NewFileAzDataLakeGen2Item {
    param (
        $Context,
        $FileSystem,
        $Source,
        $Path
        
    )
    Try{
        New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $Context -FileSystem $FileSystem -Path $Path -Source $Source -Force
        return $true
    }
    catch{
        $_.Exception
        Write-Output $Test
        return $false
    }

}
```

I'm trying to run this code from my AD account which has the storage blob contributor role. Uploading the items while using the microsoft azure storage explorer works just fine.

Comment: Did you find the answer?  I have the same error.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: In my case it was a region outage.  I switched to a different region.